# Array not returning most frequent value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

```
def most_common_letter(string)
  letter = nil
  final_letter = nil
  letter_count = nil
  idx1 = 0
  idx2 = 0
  count = 0
  while idx1 < string.length
    letter = string[idx1]
    while idx2 < string.length
      if letter == string[idx2]
        count += 1
      end
    idx2 += 1
    end
    if (letter_count == nil) || (count > letter_count)
      letter_count = count
      final_letter = letter
    end
  idx1 += 1
  end
  arr = []
  arr.push(final_letter)
  arr.push(letter_count)
  return arr
end

puts(most_common_letter("abbab") == ["b", 3])
#should be true
```

Keep getting [a,2] which leads me to believe it is only executing parts of the code when in my mind the code should be resetting the value of final letter and letter count every time there is a more frequent letter. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Because idx2 is not being reset for every iteration of idx1

Answer (score 2):

Often a counting hash is used for this type of problem:

```
def most_frequent_letter(str)
  str.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |c,h| h[c] += 1 }.max_by(&:last)
end

most_frequent_letter("bananas are so-so")
  #=> ["a",4]
```

The steps:

```
h = "bananas are so-so".each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |c,h| h[c] += 1 }
  #=> {"b"=>1, "a"=>4, "n"=>2, "s"=>3, " "=>2, "r"=>1, "e"=>1, "o"=>2, "-"=>1}
h.max_by(&:last) 
  #=> ["a",4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easier way to solve this:

```
def most_common_letter(string)
  letters = string.split('').sort!
  frequency = letters.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h,v| h[v] += 1; h }
  frequency.max_by{|k,v| v}
end

most_common_letter("abbab")
 => ["b", 3]
```

Let me go through this code line-by-line to explain.

1) Get the letters of the string and sort them alphabetically:

```
string = "abbab"

letters = string.split('').sort!
=> ["a", "a", "b", "b", "b"]
```

2) Create a hash with keys (letters) and values (occurrence)

```
frequency = letters.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h,v| h[v] += 1; h }
 => {"a"=>2, "b"=>3}
```

3) Find the highest value, and return the key value pair as an array.

```
frequency.max_by{|k,v| v}
 => ["b", 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are running into is that you are not resetting your idx2 after the loop.

You can debug this if you `puts` the idx two as follows:

```
def most_common_letter(string)
  letter = nil
  final_letter = nil
  letter_count = nil
  idx1 = 0
  idx2 = 0
  count = 0
  while idx1 < string.length
    letter = string[idx1]
    while idx2 < string.length
      if letter == string[idx2]
        count += 1
      end
      idx2 += 1
    end
    puts "#{idx2}"    #=> This is always 5
    if (letter_count == nil) || (count > letter_count)
      letter_count = count
      final_letter = letter
    end
  idx1 += 1
  end
  arr = []
  arr.push(final_letter)
  arr.push(letter_count)
  return arr
end

puts(most_common_letter("abbab"))
```

Your algorithm is simply doing the following:

comparing idx1 with idx2:

str[0] with str[0]

str[0] with str[1]

str[0] with str[2]

str[0] with str[3]

str[0] with str[4]

then idx2 is out of range and will never satisfy `idx2 < string.length` again, because the value is not reset.

This is where the logical error is. I won't give you another solution because it seems like you are trying to figure this out on your own. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def most_common_letter(str)
  str.chars.
    group_by{|v| v}.
    map{|k, l| [k, l.size]}.
    sort_by{|k, size| size}.
    last
end
```

Now:

> puts(most_common_letter("abbab") == ["b", 3])
>     # true